# Store ouput over ssh using Net::SSH::Expect

Tags: perl, ssh

student worker here. It's my first time working with perl, and I seem to have ran out of solutions, so I need your help!

I'm trying to store the ouput of a command on an HP Storeonce 3540 in a variable through the ssh module so I can extract some
information I want to monitor:

Not sure if it's useful, but FYI the output is this:

system/show> performance

```
Service Set 1
 Storage Usage
   Current: xxxxx TB
   Maximum: xxxxx TB
 Throughput
   VTL Read: 0 MB/s
   VTL Write: 0 MB/s
   NAS Read: 0 MB/s
   NAS Write: 0 MB/s
   Catalyst Read: 0 MB/s
   Catalyst Write: 0 MB/s
 Replication
   Inbound: 0 MB/s
   Outbound: 0 MB/s
 Catalyst
   Inbound: 0 MB/s
   Outbound: 0 MB/s
```

Here's the code:

```
use Net::SSH::Expect;
use Capture::Tiny ':all';
use Backticks;
( ... )
  my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
          host => $hp_host,
          password=> $hp_pwd,
          user => $hp_user,
          raw_pty => 1,
          timeout => 20
         );
  my $login_output = $ssh->login();
  if ($login_output !~ />/)
   {
    die "Login has failed. Login output was $login_output";
   }
  $ssh->send("system");
  $ssh->waitfor('\>\s*\z', 5) or die "Error #1-system";
  $ssh->send("show");
  $ssh->waitfor('\>\s*\z', 5) or die "Error #2-show";
```

Here I want to store the "performance" command's output.
  I have tried a bunch of combinations so here it goes:

1 - 
`say '$ssh->send("performance")'->stdout;`

gets me this error:

`String found where operator expected at script_hpstoreonce.pl line 67, near "say '$ssh->send("performance")'"
        (Do you need to predeclare say?)
syntax error at script_hpstoreonce.pl line xx, near "say '$ssh->send("performance")'"`

2 - 
`Backticks->run( '$ssh->send("performance")' );
print $stdout;`

It does not print the output

3 - 
Every time I put the `"$ssh-> "` in front of the command I get this error:

ex:
`$ssh->Backticks->run( 'send("performance")' );`
or
`$string = $ssh->tee('performance');`

error:
`Can't locate object method "Backticks"/or("Tee")/ via package "Net::SSH::Expect" at script_hpstoreonce.pl line xx.`

4 - 
 `$test = Backticks->stdout('performance');
 print $stdout;`
 or
 `print $test;`

error:
`Can't locate object method "Backticks" via package "Net::SSH::Expect" at script_hpstoreonce.pl line xx.`

5 - 
I also tried to use the Capture::Tiny module but again:

`$stdout = capture { $ssh->send("performance") };
 print $stdout;`

gets me this error:

`Can't locate object method "capture" via package "Net::SSH::Expect" at script_hpstoreonce.pl line xx.`

but

`($stdout, $stderr) = capture {$ssh->send("performance")};
  print $stdout;`

or

`$stdout = capture_stdout{$ssh->exec("performance")};
 print $stdout;`

or

`my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->send('performance');
 print $stdout;`

or

`$stdout = $ssh->capture('performance');
 print $stdout;`

Does not print anything when I run the script.

6 - 
Same thing goes for Tee:

`$string = tee {$ssh->send("performance")};
 print $string;`

Doesn't print anything

Since the same errors are popping up even when I use different modules, I understand that I'm probably
 missing something due to my lack of knowledge of the language and my lack of experience, but I can't 
 seem to find what's wrong here. Is the problem in the `$ssh->` protocole??

Thank you

Comment: `send` doesn't return anything so there isnt' anything to store. What exactly are you trying to get back and have you read the cpan docs on the module?http://search.cpan.org/~bnegrao/Net-SSH-Expect-1.09/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pod

Comment: i'm trying to get back the output of the system/show/performance command. I want to put that output in a string to extract some information with a regex (but for now just to put the output in a string is what I'm asking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl will mostly collect all sorts of output without need of additional packages. It's only special cases where you need something extra. In this case just the Net::SSH::Expect would be enough.

I don't have Net::SSH::Expect on my system however it seems like what you need is:

```
$ssh->send("find /");   # using send() instead of exec()
my $line;
while ( defined ($line = $ssh->read_line()) ) {
  print $line . "\n";  
}
```

For something as short as what you have shown I'd be inclined to skip the complexity of send and read_line and just go with exec.

```
my $who = $ssh->exec("who");
print ($who);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the output of the commands in 1 report try this

```
use Net::SSH::Expect
use strict;
use warnings;

my $stdout = $ssh->exec($command);
my $stdout2 = $ssh->exec($command);

my $filename = 'report.txt';
open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
print $fh "$stdout" . "$stdout2";
close $fh;
print "done\n";
```

This should Print both variables into a .txt report